# VBA Dates: Cannot Get the Format Correct

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

I'm trying to convert a date from something like Month/Day/Year to fully spelled out, like May 31st, 2014.

I hit a roadblock. Currently, I'm using this, and when the Message Box pops up, if has the correct date (May 31st, 2014), but once I write it to a cell, it converts to a number (From 5/31/14 to 41790). I'm lost and would love some assistance. Thanks!

```
Dim whatever as String
whatever = Format("5/31/14","mmmm dd, yyyy")
MsgBox whatever
ActiveWorkbook.Activesheet.Cells(1,1) = whatever
```

I have a program that uses the data from the sheet to run a Mail Merge in word, so I'm trying to get the entire date written out and not just simply format the cell, because Word takes the raw data (from what I know.)

Comment: Use `Format` when you apply to the actual cell.

Comment: Look at the `MONTHNAME` function and just write the value directly to the cell... something like `whatever = Monthname(myDate) & " " & Day(myDate) & ", " & Year(myDate)`

Comment: add `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).NumberFormat = "@"` before placing the data in .

Comment: I used your method Scott. It worked! Thank you so much :D All of you really

Answer (score 2):

When you are trying to display your format in the cell the correct way is to change the cell's number format and then set the cell's value

e.g.

```
Cells(1,1).NumberFormat="MMM DD, YYYY"
Cells(1,1).Value2= Date
```

Comment: You can set the format before or after in Excel, it makes no difference as you're formatting the display value anyway - not the cell's value. That aside - this is the correct answer for what OP wants to do.

Comment: Does it though?  OP's example desired date format was May 31st, 2014 - IIRC, this would give May 31, 2014?  Willing to acknowledge that I might be wrong though!

Answer (score 1):

To get a date in **ordinal format**, consider:

```
Public Function OrdinalDate(d As Date) As String
    Dim dy As Long, mnth As String, yr As Long
    Dim s As String
    ar = Array("th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th")

    dy = Day(d)
    mnth = MonthName(Month(d))
    yr = Year(d)

    If dy > 10 And dy < 20 Then
        s = "th"
    Else
        s = ar(dy Mod 10)
    End If

    OrdinalDate = dy & s & " " & mnth & " " & yr
End Function
```

[image]

Of course to **remove** the ordinal designation does not require *VBA*.  With the ordinal form in **B1**, use:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,MID(B1,FIND(" ",B1)-2,2),""))
```

[image]

and we are back where we started.